# Is it possible to launch a specific webpage on Android after scanning a QR code for connecting to WiFi?

Tags: javascript, android, wifi, qr-code

I recently found out you can use QR codes to share WiFi credentials (so those who scan can easily connect to WiFi).

Is it possible to make the Android device launch a specific webpage after they've connected to WiFi (after scanning such a QR code)?

Or, is it possible to make an Android phone connect to WiFi when they visit a specific website (eg. via some JS code)?

Comment: "you can use QR codes to share WiFi credentials" -- not every device model will support this. "is it possible to make an Android phone connect to WiFi when they visit a specific website" -- that is a security nightmare, so I sincerely hope that's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The WLAN-Acces QR code has (as far as i know) the following structure:

```
WIFI:T:<AuthType>;S:<SSID>;P:<PW/PSK>:H:<Hidden>;
```

Ther is no field to load a specific page afterwards.

Also connecting to a network via JS is not possible since it would be a real thread.

BUT what you can do is to use a WLAN Captive Portal.